# Slow and laggy animation of an electromagnetic wave

Tags: plotting, manipulate, graphics3d, animation, version-7

I made a *manipulate* code of an electromagnetic plane wave which works relatively well, but is very slow and laggy for what it does (showing just a bunch of rotating or oscillating arrows).  What is wrong with the code below, and how could I make it faster (smoother animation) ?

```
circ = 1; (* circ = 0 for linear polarisation *)
n = {1, 0, 0};  (* direction of propagation *)
a = {0, 1, 0};  (* linear polarisation vector *)
b = {0, 0, 1};

Efield[t_, x_] := - a Sin[2 π (x - t)] - circ b Cos[2 π (x - t)]
Bfield[t_, x_] := - b Sin[2 π (x - t)] + circ a Cos[2 π (x - t)]
VectE[t_, x_] :=  Arrow[{x n , x n + (1/4) Efield[t, x]}]
VectB[t_, x_] :=  Arrow[{x n , x n + (1/4) Bfield[t, x]}]

EMarrows[t_] := Graphics3D[{
    Table[{Arrowheads[Medium], Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.80], VectE[t, x]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, 1/12}],
    Table[{Arrowheads[Medium], Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.80, 0.40], VectB[t, x]}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, 1/12}]
    }]

EMwave[t_] := ParametricPlot3D[{
    x n + (1/4) Efield[t, x],
    x n + (1/4) Bfield[t, x]
    }, {x, -1.5, 1.5},
    PlotStyle -> {
        {Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.80]},
        {Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.80, 0.40]}
    },
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"
    ]

Manipulate[
    Show[EMarrows[t], EMwave[t],
        PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}},
        AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.7], Dashed],
        SphericalRegion -> True,
        ImageSize -> {800, 800}
    ],
    {{t, 0, "t"}, 0, 10, 0.01, AnimationRate -> 0.1, RefreshRate -> 30, 
    Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}},
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

Take note that the first parameter : `circ`, could be changed to any number `-1 < circ < 1`, `circ = 0` for a linearly polarized wave.

Comment: It animates pretty smoothly for me. Did you try just the arrows or just the curves, to see if either one in particular is causing the problem?

Comment: @SimonWoods, yes, of course.  The curves are okay.  The arrows alone are laggy.  The animation is "jumping" from one frame to another, and I'm unable to make it smooth.

Comment: And I must say that I don't understand well the relation between **AnimationRate** and **RefreshRate**.  It doesn't help much here, except the **AnimationRate** since I want a relatively slow (and smooth) propagation of the wave.

Comment: I wonder if your using V7 isn't contributing to the problem. `Manipulate` was still rather new when V7 was released. I believe it has received a lot of development since then. I think it likely that those of us who are using much later releases are going to have trouble reproducing your problem.

Comment: @m_goldberg, yes version 7 may be the cause of my problem.  So is the animation code above very smooth for you ?  I may have to think about upgrading Mathematica, but it is costly for an individual.

Comment: Yes, it runs smoothly and looks very good on my system, which is V10.3.1 running on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks.  So my version is really outdated.  And I'm still on OS X 10.6.11 (Snow Leopard), on a 5 years old Mac mini.

Comment: I think you should upgrade OS X before upgrading _Mathematica_. You can do that for free and that, in itself, might improve graphics performance. Further, I don't think V10.3.1 will run on Snow Leopard. Upgrading from Snow Leopard to Yosemite is certainly doable -- it's what I did. My computer is a 2010 iMac, so your mini, which is newer, should support upgrading at least to the software level that I have installed..

Comment: @m_goldberg, actually, my mini is from 2010 too.  I don't intent to upgrading the OS on this machine, so this is one main reason why I'm still on Mathematica 7.  One of these days, when the mini dies, I'll upgrade the machine and Mathematica.  What are the actual options to buy Mathematica for a personal use at home only ?  And I'm a teacher.    The full Mathematica is several thousands of $ !

Comment: I am not the person to ask about buying _Mathematica_. I have the standard edition on the year-by-year basis. It's all I know about. You should go to the Wolfram site for buying options. As a teacher you should qualify for a very low price.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the performance of graphics in a very old version of _Mathematica_ that no one other than the OP can reproduce -- mostly because we don't have V7.

Comment: @m_goldberg, it's okay with me.  I adopted a different strategy anyway.

Comment: Under Windows 7 this is definitely smoother in v10.1.0 than it is in v7.0.1.